# Show the Listview only when the search string is entered

Tags: android, listview

I want the `listView` to be displayed only when a search string is inserted in the `EditText`. Below is my code...Please help me I would be highly obliged...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ListView mSearchNFilterLv;

    private EditText mSearchEdt;

    private ArrayList<String> mStringList;

    private ValueAdapter valueAdapter;

    private TextWatcher mSearchTw;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initUI();

        initData();

        valueAdapter = new ValueAdapter(mStringList, this);

        mSearchNFilterLv.setAdapter(valueAdapter);

        mSearchEdt.addTextChangedListener(mSearchTw);


        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }


    private void initData() {

        mStringList = new ArrayList<String>();

        mStringList.add("one");

        mStringList.add("two");

        mStringList.add("three");

        mStringList.add("four");

        mStringList.add("five");

        mStringList.add("six");

        mStringList.add("seven");

        mStringList.add("eight");

        mStringList.add("nine");

        mStringList.add("ten");

        mStringList.add("eleven");

        mStringList.add("twelve");

        mStringList.add("thirteen");

        mStringList.add("fourteen");

        mSearchTw = new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                valueAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(mSearchEdt.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE)
                    mSearchEdt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };

    }

    private void initUI() {

        mSearchNFilterLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        mSearchEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the code below:

```
mSearchTw = new TextWatcher() {
      @Override public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

      }

      @Override public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if (s != null && s.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
          mSearchNFilterLv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
          mSearchNFilterLv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
      }

      @Override public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      }
    };
```

This will show the ListView when there is an entered text (while entering text to EditText) and if text has 1 or more characters.

If you want ListView to be changed only when the insertion is over move the given code inside `onTextChanged` to `afterTextChanged`

**PS:** You can use the same structure with SearchView instead of EditText with query listeners.

**Updated**

You can use below code to hide ListView initially:

```
private void initUI() {
    mSearchNFilterLv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    mSearchEdt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_search);
    mSearchNFilterLv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for the help... But it's still showing the contents of the listView when the app opens initially...Can you please help me with that too...

Comment: @ManujSankrit no problem! Can you mark the answer as accepted and upvote it if this helped you?